# Match columns and Highlight results in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, window

I want to find matches between two columns  and highlight the results of both columns, in a pandas dataframes, so I did this code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Zea mays','Zea mays subsp. mexicana','Zea mays subsp. parviglumis'],'ID':[1,2,3],'type':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.1':['Zea mays subsp. huehuetenangensis','Zea mays subsp. mays','Zea mays'],'ID.1':[1,2,3],'type.1':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.2':['Zea nicaraguensis','Zea luxurians','Zea perennis'],'ID.2':[1,2,3],'type.2':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.3':['Capsicum annuum','Capsicum frutescens','Capsicum chinense'],'ID.3':[1,2,3],'type.3':[1.1,1.2,1.3]})

def in_statements(s):
    color = 'yellow'
    if np.where(str(s.iloc[4]) == str(s.iloc[8])):
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'black'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
df.style.applymap(in_statements)
```

However, it gives me this error: " ("'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index Samples')"

This is an example of the input:

[image]

This is how it should lool:
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: provide an example of the input dataframe, along with ur expected output.

Comment: I edited my question to have the desired input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want highlight duplicated values in `Name`s columns use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with mask creted by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for columns with `Name`, reshaped by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), get duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and reshaped back by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Dog','Dog.1','Dog.3'],'ID':[1,2,3],'type':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.1':['Dog','cat','Dog.3'],'ID.1':[1,2,3],'type.1':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.2':['cat','cat.12','Dog.1'],'ID.2':[1,2,3],'type.2':[1.1,1.2,1.3],
                 'Name.3':['cat.7','cat.13','Dog.3'],'ID.3':[1,2,3],'type.3':[1.1,1.2,1.3]})

print (df)
    Name  ID  type Name.1  ID.1  type.1  Name.2  ID.2  type.2  Name.3  ID.3  \
0    Dog   1   1.1    Dog     1     1.1     cat     1     1.1   cat.7     1   
1  Dog.1   2   1.2    cat     2     1.2  cat.12     2     1.2  cat.13     2   
2  Dog.3   3   1.3  Dog.3     3     1.3   Dog.1     3     1.3   Dog.3     3   

   type.3  
0     1.1  
1     1.2  
2     1.3  

def color(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c = '' 
    #compare columns
    names = x.filter(like='Name')
    mask = names.stack().duplicated(keep=False).unstack()
    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled empty strings
    df1 =  pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #modify values of df1 column by boolean mask
    df1 = names.mask(mask, c1).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1, fill_value='')
    return df1


df.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel('df.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you also write the output to an excell file? Because when I try to do it, I get this error: "Result of must have identical index and columns as the input"

Comment: @Sofia - I try understand green highlight values, but failed. Can you explain it? Also [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: So dog is repeated in the same three columns, and then cat is repeated as well. Thats wayt it is repeated... Basically the green color matched the same word repeated in the other columns.

Comment: @jezrael- I just added the dataframe in pandas, thanks for the help :)

Comment: I edited the pandas dataframe, to show you my real situation. Cause I get this error:  bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'. Can you see if you get this error? I'm so sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Sofia try change `df1 = names.mask(mask, c1).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1, fill_value='')` to `df1 = names.mask(mask.fillna(False), c1).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1, fill_value='')`

Comment: @jezreal in order to the code to work I had to change it to:names.mask(mask.fillna(True), c1).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1, fill_value=''). But in this way, I get also the blank row to be colored...